# Error while using choice method from random module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, helper

I was doing a small project to randomly change the surname among the names taken as input from the user.

```
def randomize(names):
    import random
    firstname = []
    surname = []
    n = 0
    for j in range(len(names)):
        name1 = names[j].split()
        firstname.append(name1[0])
        surname.append(name1[1])
    print(firstname)
    print(surname)
    while n < len(names):
        firstname = random.choice(firstname)
        surname = random.choice(surname)
        n += 1
        print(firstname + " " + surname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = []
    number = int(input("Enter the number of students\n"))
    for i in range(number):
        name.append(input("Enter the names\n"))
    randomize(name)
```

It is working first at the first time but from the second line it is only printing letters repeatadly.

Comment: `firstname = random.choice(firstname)`, do you know what you are doing?

Comment: You didn't mean to overwrite the `firstname` and `surname` variables. Perhaps you meant to write: `print(random.choice(firstname)+ " " + random.choice(surname))`

Comment: I am sorry I didn't noticed it in the go, Now when I went through the code again I got it and its working and I have posted the code down. Thank you for taking time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def randomize(names):
    import random
    firstname = []
    surname = []
    n = 0
    for j in range(len(names)):
        name1 = names[j].split()
        firstname.append(name1[0])
        surname.append(name1[1])
    while n < len(names):
        firstname1 = random.choice(firstname)
        firstname.remove(firstname1)
        surname1 = random.choice(surname)
        surname.remove(surname1)
        print(firstname1 + " " + surname1)
        n += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = []
    number = int(input("Enter the number of students\n"))
    for i in range(number):
        name.append(input("Enter the names\n"))
    randomize(name)
```

Got it. Thank you for looking into this. It was due to my hurry that I missed a small detail. I got the answer when I read it again.